# “Please specify the product's option(s)” message occuring after clicking on add to cart button on product detail page

Tags: php, magento

After Installing new themeforest magnium theme on our magento website version CE Magento 1.9.0.1.  Mageworx "Advanced custom Options" extensions  is not working.

So I don't understand which file has been override.

Actually issue is that when I click on add to cart button on product detail page then custom options not adding to cart page and occurring error message “Please specify the product's option(s)” on same product detail page.

Comment: this is because you are not selecting the custom option and adding the product

Comment: It's required then I added custom options value for that configurable product. but still same issue exists.

Comment: give me the link of your website..

Comment: https://www.jamesleonard.com/development/barton-perreira-hettie-eyeglasses.html

Comment: ok wait..........

Comment: There is some options which are required but not posted. which extension you are using?

Comment: Mageworx "Advanced Product options"

Comment: Ask them for support.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because the extension from Mageworx is overriding a template file that the theme is also overriding. You need to open the source of the Mageworx plugin, find all templates in the template folder, and incorporate their differences into your Magnium theme template folder.

More specifically- you're getting this error because the configurable options are not posting when adding to cart. This is likely because their name is incorrect in the template or they aren't output. (Replacing the Magnium theme templates with the Mageworx templates should bring this functionality back)

Either way, this is a question for the Support team on the extension or theme you are using- not really something appropriate for a stack question.